# ytdl-core latest version : Uncaught SyntaxError evalmachine.<anonymous>:25

Tags: ytdl

I don't know why I have this error because two days before update the module, it was perfectly working...

For exemple here is a function that plays music on discord :

```
async function play(args) {
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
channelId: interaction.member.voice.channel.id,
guildId: interaction.guild.id,
adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
selfDeaf: false,
selfMute: false
});
const stream =  ytdl(args, { filter: "audioonly", quality: "highestaudio", highWaterMark: 1 << 25 })
const resource = createAudioResource(stream)
connection.subscribe(player)
player.play(resource)  
console.log("yay")
await ytdl.getInfo(args).then(songInfo => {
var nom = {
title :songInfo.videoDetails.title,
url : songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
mingnature : songInfo.videoDetails.thumbnails
}
console.log(nom.mingnature[0].url)
const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor("#FF0000")
.setTitle('**AudioPlayer**')
.setURL('https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ')
.setDescription('__Le player joue de la musique !__')
.setImage(nom.mingnature[0].url)
.addFields({ name: '__Titre__', value: '\u200b' + nom.title, inline: true }, {name: "__Url__", value : "\u200B" + nom.url, inline : false})
.setTimestamp()
.setFooter({ text: 'Sponsorisé par le gouvernement chinois', iconURL: 'https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.28d8e003d4e8edb2f7d11d79ec49007b?rik=cuyzYTTdr2QpBQ&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwww.conservativehome.com%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2013%2f10%2fChinese-flag.jpg&ehk=IQVZcYPrGiV1wP4hGvjvss7uhK%2f6EQuXpmHL07sMpF4%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0' });
interaction.channel.send({embeds : [exampleEmbed]})
})
}
```

This function perfectly working but now it returns

```
Uncaught SyntaxError evalmachine.<anonymous>:25
[])||(0,c[2])((0,c[45])((0,c[25])(c[21],c[55],(0,c[11])()),c[2],(0,c[86])(c[55],c[53]),c[13],c[77],c[27]),c[52],c[62],c[74]),1==c[43]&&((0,c[45])((0,c[2])((0,c[13])(c[65+Math.pow(3,2)%391],c[85]),c[78],c[35],c[68]),c[2],((0,c[76])(c[3],c[77]),c[40])(c[77]),c[40],c[87]),1)||(((((0,c[13])(c[87],c[65]),c[52])(c[46],c[Math.pow(5,3)%149+-51]),c[47])(c[63],c[1]),c[62])(c[50],c[18]),c[28])(c[56],c[50])};lma(ncode);
^
```

The problem is not from my code but it's somewhere else
It's very strange...

There is also this error after the big error :

```
SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try
at Script (vm:100:7)
at exports.decipherFormats (c:\Users\cash\Desktop\palaexpress bot\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\sig.js:116:51)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I have a problem to understand it too, thank for answer !

Answer (score 1):

This is a newly documented issue, check out proposed solutions here: https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/issues/1197

Comment: I read it and at the final, I think we should wait that the ytdl-core will be updated and run the code with the 4.10.0 version

Comment: Use the 4.9.1 version, it's works because 4.10.0 is too slow

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.